# clearing mapoverlays

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have a List variable named ArrowOverlays defined at the activity level.  I have the following method that moves an arrow around a google mapview...

```
    private void moveTheArrow(GeoPoint whereTo)
{
    if (ArrowOverlays.isEmpty() == false)
    {
        ArrowOverlays.clear();  //this gets a NullPointer exception
    }
    myMapView.getOverlays().clear();  //this works but clears all overlays
    ArrowOverlays = myMapView.getOverlays(); 
    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow); 
    myItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new myItemizedOverlay(drawable, PSContext);

    GeoPoint point = whereTo;
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "string1", "string2");

    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

    ArrowOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);     

}
```

I have several other overlays on the mapview in addition to this one.  What I want to do is to clear ArrowOverlays with an ArrowOverlays.Clear() instruction but it blows with a nullpointer exception.  I don't know why this is happening.  The MapView.GetOverlays().Clear() works fine but it clears all of the overlays on the map.  How can I clear just the ArrowOverllays collection?
Thanks,
Dean

Comment: Please post the code for the ArrowOverlay.clear() method.

Comment: @VishwaPatel I guess, He can't paste it... :)

Comment: Oh my bad, I forgot it was a List.